# Questions about moving to Git on VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

We've been using TFS for many years but are considering moving to VSTS, possibly with a switch to Git (our company was taken over recently and the new owners use Git). I've been having a quick play with GitHub (not VSTS), and have a few questions...

**Local repo**

I'm struggling to get my head around the idea of first having to commit to a local repo *then* to the server. It seems like an unnecessary extra step, and I'm not sure what the benefits are?

**Branching**

Git recommends creating a branch each time you want to develop a new feature or fix a bug. Our team might churn out dozens of new features in a sprint, so I'm a bit concerned about the resulting explosion of branches, the overhead of managing them, and the possible confusion/mistakes that could result. I realise you can delete a branch when you've done with it, but it's still an unwanted overhead and I *know* our devs will forget to clean up after themselves!

With TFS we commit changes straight to the master (dev) branch, and the only time we create a branch is when releasing a new version of the product. We'll create a "Release_1.0" branch for example, and the only time we would work on this is to fix a bug (then merge it back into "dev").

We obviously don't have to follow the "Git way", but I'm wondering what the pros and cons are of this workflow?

**Work Items**

Am I right in saying that work items can be associated with a Git "commit"? Is it nicely integrated like it is with TFS, or is it more of an after-thought/hack approach? I don't want this sort of thing to become a hindrance to our devs.

**Builds**

We're still running TFS2012, and have customised our build processes (e.g. to update version numbers in AssemblyInfo.cs, run StyleCop, create an InnoSetup script, etc). This may or may not be specific to Git, but is it still possible to manage and customise builds in VSTS? I'm assuming builds run on the VSTS servers, therefore there would be some cost involved for their CPU time?

Comment: Why the close vote? The MSDN VSTS forum has now been locked, and requests that people ask their questions here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The idea of creating local commits is not an overhead but a feature which allows you to do anything while working locally. You can create/amend/delete commits as long as you haven't pushed them. It gives you the flexibility which I am sure you will love once you get accustomed.
2. Branches in git are cheap. You will probably maintain a master branch and some of the releases branches. Apart from that whenever you want to develop some feature, you will create a new branch out of master, commit your changes, push the changes to server and create a pull request and then merge it back to master and delete the branch. VSTS allows easily deleting branches when it is merged. Git also has the option of deleting all the branches which are merged to master. To take your bug fixes to master or releases branches, you can use the git cherry pick feature which has first class support in VSTS UI.
3. Yes, there is first class support for linking work items to commits and pull requests.
4. Yes, you can customize your build however you want. Git is only a version control system. Your build pipeline can remain the same.